# Zoom class before Shacharis?

Tags: halacha, shacharis-morning-prayer

I have a zoom class, based on in the UK, which starts at 5:00 AM Canada time. I get up around 4:30 am, which is already past Alot Hashachar. There is the heter to continue working if I started before Alot but this won't apply here for the above reason.

Some also permit doing mitzvot before davening, so the question is, is this class a mitzvah? TYVM.

Comment: What's the class on? I'm not sure how it would be a mitzvah unless it's Torah.

Comment: This question is probably relevant regardless of zoom.

Comment: Is the class about learning a profession so you can support yourself in the future?